# Is it possible to show image or video in IOS platform when outgoing or incoming call?

Tags: ios, iphone, video

I want to develop application to show user video or image when someone is calling me. I know it is possible on android, but i don't know about ios platform. Is it possible to do such an application ?

Answer (score 2):

Apps can only modify things within their own sandbox. The incoming call screen, is part of the phone app and therefore can't be modified. The only way to do this would be on a jailbroken iPhone, and it would be quite difficult.